# Looking to add VIF to export_summs logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm looking to add VIF to logistic regression in R, using the `export_summs` function.
This is the current code:

```r
export_summs(model1,model2, error_format = "({p.value})", exp = TRUE)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is `export_summs` from (it's not base R) and what does it do? What is VIF? Please make your example reproducible by including sample data. We don't know anything about `model1` and `model2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use library car package and find vif(model1) or vif(model2) to find multicollinearity

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get VIF of a logistic regression model using `jtools` package in r. `Your_glm_model` is your logistic model that is returned from `glm` function.

```
summ(`Your_glm_model`, vifs = TRUE)
```